# postfix connection to python-libmilter test-milter

Tags: postfix, python, milter

From the [python-libmilter](https://github.com/crustymonkey/python-libmilter) I am trying to run the [test milter](https://github.com/crustymonkey/python-libmilter/blob/master/examples/testmilter.py).

The milter is listening (I can connect via telnet to localhost 5000)

I enabled the milter in the postfix config:

```
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = tcp:127.0.0.1:5000 unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = tcp:127.0.0.1:5000 unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

Thus, the testmilter should be called before the opendkim milter.
(postfix was of course restarted)

However, I don't get any log from the testmilter when I send an email.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It must be `inet:127.0.0.1:5000` instead of `tcp:127.0.0.1:5000` (emphasis on **inet** vs **tcp**)